# Error in loading Javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have requirement in which I need to load application using Ajax, in the application I am loading few javascripts.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>
```

Now the problem is that, When I load application directly (without ajax) it works fine, but when I load application using ajax; javascripts are not getting loaded.

Comment: If I understood the situation correctly, jquery library is being included more than once in a single page?

Comment: it's just an example, it could be other js also.

Comment: Do you use live() or on() of jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to dynamically load JavaScript files?

If so, AJAX is not your friend. You can just add a SCRIPT tag to the DOM.

```
var jsTag = document.createElement("script");
jsTag.src = "some.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(jsTag);
```

Of course, this particular example requires that you have a body element to attach the script tag to...

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ajax method `ajax.getScript` ,i guess you are doing dynamic loading,so you need to register scrips after ajax call.

refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/